# Where do external API calls go in a node/express project?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

I'm making a single page web app with express, and for the data I'm making an external API call that returns JSON with data that I'm formatting and presenting.

My question is whether I should have the external API call in the route file? Usually, if I was using a DB, I would have a model folder, but with no database in this instance I'm wondering if I should still separate the calls to the API from the routes file.

If so, should it be in a models folder? If another folder, what would it be called?

Thanks!

Comment: You can have an `API` inside the `routes` directory and have your API endpoints in there.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, Create prefix of each routes for external api. This is best approach.

Comment: Thank you! So you would suggest multiple files in the 'route' folder, with each one referencing the start of the different paths that I'm calling the external api with?

Comment: @RobertFaldo with express the file structure doesn't have to match the routing. you can organize the files however best suits you (for example, clumping related functions together). for example you could have a fruits.js to add fruit, remove fruit, modify fruit taking `fruit/orange/add` `fruit/apple/edit` and performing related operations. I might clump `/login` and `/logout` under the same file etc.

Comment: @RobertFaldo all depend upon you how you can organize files. This is simple suggestion for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a seperate file called utils.js or services.js and inside that you can create multiple functions corresponding to different external api calls.